# Can I write gradle buildSrc in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'd like to write my Gradle buildSrc in Kotlin instead of Java, since everything else is Kotlin too.

I've tried `.kt` files in `buildSrc/src/main/kotlin` and in `buildSrc/src/main/java`, but neither will be compiled. IntelliJ does recognize them at least when I put them in `/java`, but they are not found when running Gradle tasks.

So, how do I make Gradle look at Kotlin build sources?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`buildSrc`is treated as an *included build*, and you can use any supported language inside this project, as long as you apply the needed plugins.

Following setup should work :

**buildSrc/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm") version "1.3.72"
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

custom task:

**buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/tasks/MyKtTask.kt**

```
package tasks

import org.gradle.api.DefaultTask
import org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskAction

open class MyKtTask : DefaultTask() {

    @TaskAction
    fun execute() {
        println("kotlin tasks executed")
    }

}
```

Using the custom task:

**build.gradle**

```
task "testKt" (type: tasks.MyKtTask){
    doLast{
        // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: Yep, adding a `build.gradle` for `buildSrc` did the trick. My googling so far hadn't produced that option.

Comment: Alternatively, to avoid specifying a kotlin version, you can use `plugins { \`kotlin-dsl\` }` in buildSrc/build.gradle